# given string and its substring, how could I add white space before substring using unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Assume the substring is unique, for example, given string,

```
"123 main streetHuntington, WV"
```

How could I locate the Huntington and add a white space before it.

```
"123 main street Huntington, WV"
```

Comment: Have you tried `sed`?

Comment: Or even a vim macro?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# perl
echo "123 main streetHuntington, WV" | perl -ne 's/(Huntington)/ $1/;print'
# sed
echo "123 main streetHuntington, WV" | sed 's/\(Huntington\)/ \1/'
```

Comment: I hope this wasn't downvoted just because a shorter sed expression exists: `sed 's/Huntington/ &/'`. +1 from me to cancel the downvote

Comment: @user000001 I think its more because it's an stupid answer. No reflection, no help, just some code. But stupid questions ~= stupid anwser. IMO is glenn jackman's answer better :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are parsing arbitrary addresses, [this is a very hard problem](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

Assuming you're not just trying to put a space in that specific string, you might want to add a space before an uppercase letter that is preceded by a lower case letter.

```
sed -r 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/\1 \2/g'
```

Comment: Quite right. If the actual question is "I need to add a space between the street name and the city, but I don't know exactly the city name", then there's no answer. If the actual question is as stated, then the easiest answer is to do it manually with a text editor.